# Angularjs - Array items dependent property not updating

Tags: angularjs, global-variables

I have this scope array variable

```
$scope.menuItems = [
        {
            name: 'Login',
            url:'#/login',
            isAvailable: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Register',
            url: '#/register',
            isAvailable: $scope.global.roleId == null
        },
        {
            name: 'My Restaurants',
            url: '#/myrestaurants',
            isAvailable: $scope.global.roleId == constants.OWNER_USER_ROLE_ID
        },
        {
            name: 'Create Restaurant',
            url: '#/createrestaurant',
            isAvailable: $scope.global.roleId == constants.OWNER_USER_ROLE_ID
        },
        {
            name: 'Logout',
            url: '#/logout',
            isAvailable: $scope.global.roleId != null
        }
    ];
```

This object is dependent on another scope variable `$scope.global.roleId`

I am loading menu from this array like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-repeat="n in menuItems | filter:{isAvailable:true}">
        <a href="{{n.url}}">{{n.name}}</a>
    </li>                      
</ul>
```

And I want it to update menus automatically when `$scope.global.roleId` is updated.

To be noted, I am updating this variable `$scope.global.roleId` from a child controller and this field is getting updated properly but it is not affecting the array field `isAvailable`.

I checked both the variables `$scope.global.roleId` and `$scope.menuItems` in log and `$scope.global.roleId` is updating properly everytime but not `$scope.menuItems.isAvailable` field which is dependent on former

What wrong am I doing or expecting? And what is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Achieved it like this, converting variable to property

```
{
    name: 'My Restaurants',
    url: '#/myrestaurants',
    get isAvailable() {
        return $scope.global.roleId == constants.OWNER_USER_ROLE_ID;
    }
},
```